# Conditions under which a non-symmetric block matrix is diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, block-matrices

I have a $(2n)\times (2n)$ matrix defined in blocks:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
M=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
A & B\\
\hline
C & D \\
\end{array} 
\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

where $A,B,C,D$ are all $n\times n$ matrices that are real, symmetric, and positive semi-definite.

Clearly $M$ would be diagonalisable if $B=C$. I am trying to understand if I can say anything about the possibility to diagonalise $M$ when  $B \neq C$.

Any help or link to textbook would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you block-diagonalise, at least?